# Regex Skipping Similar Result

Tags: regex

I've been trying to come up with a way to resolve a situation where I'm searching through PCAP files.  I'm looking for the header "Content-Type: .*" after an HTTP OK response.  However, in an example like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
date:
asdf
X-Content-Type: aadsf
Content-Type: application/json
more: stuff

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
date:
asdf
X-Content-Type: aadsf
Content-Type: application/json
more: stuff
```

My current regex `"HTTP\/1.1 200 OK[\s\S]*?Content-Type:.*"` stops the capture group at `X-Content-Type: aadsf`.  My intent is the regex capture group to go to `Content-Type: application/json`.

Any regex wizards that can give me some pointers?

Comment: Which language are you using here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A PCRE regex without lookarounds that you may use is

```
(?m)^HTTP.*(?:\R.+)*?\RContent-Type:\s*\K.+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cHKkzy/1). If you want to make it even more efficient, [replace the first `.+` with `.++`](https://regex101.com/r/cHKkzy/2). It may easily be re-written for use with a capturing group and say (CR)?LF ending:

```
^HTTP.*(?:\r?\n.+)*?\r?\nContent-Type:\s*(.+)
```

Note that `m` multiline modifier to make `^` match start of a line might be still necessary.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a line
- `HTTP` - a substring
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `(?:\R.+)*?` - any 0+, as few as possible, sequences of a line break (`\R` or `\r?\n`) followed with 1 or more chars other than line breaks
- `\R` - a line break
- `Content-Type:` - a literal substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding all text matched so far from the current match value
- `.+` - 1 or more chars other than line breaks.

Comment: Very good (+1), this reduces the steps compared to mine dramatically.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
^HTTP             # match HTTP at the start of the line
(?s:(?!^$).)+?    # anything lazily, do not overrun an empty newline
^Content-Type:\s* # Content-Type: at the start of a line
(?P<type>.+)      # capture the type
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/9UwHds/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is regex [`^((?:X-)?Content-Type):(.*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/ILAYSC/2) which captures both content types. Or simply append `\n` (newline) before `Content-Type` if you want it to stop after one additional content type.